# How to use multips Aloha editors with different toolbars

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

On a page I'd like to have 2 div's that are editable using aloha-editor. For one field the formatting-toolbar should be available, for the other only the insert-toolbar.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to configure the format plugin on a per-editable level. There is an example at the bottom of the page in the [documentation](http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_format.html) of the format pugin.